# Calculate the excel sheet ONLY when needed

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

Need to know if `ActiveSheet.Calculate` calculates the active sheet with its dependencies like `SUMIFS(OTHER SHEETS), INDIRECT(OTHER SHEETS)` or not.

I need your help to find the proper code to trigger `ActiveSheet.Calculate` when sheet is filtered in columns, taking into account that my workbook set to manual calculation.

Comment: What exactly is the problem and what have you tried so far to solve it? From my reading it looks like there's a lot more background info in this question than there needs to be, if you could reduce it down to a concise, answerable problem that would help a lot in gaining useful answers.

Comment: Worksheet.calculate does not take account of uncalculated dependencies on other sheets. What is the reason why you cannot just press F9 whenever you want to recalculate?

Comment: @Aiken, I tried to give details that helps you have a full picture of issue i am having in order to suggest a suitable solution. And i did really concise it in this note **I need your help on this request please. If i am using the right action to recalculate only the active sheet. And What is the proper code to trigger ActiveSheet.Calculate when sheet is filtered.**

Comment: Rather than adding this information as a comment consider editing your question instead. You can do this by clicking the small 'edit' text below the question body. Simply asking for code is usually a no-go on Stack Overflow but in your case you can probably get this specific enough that it's a simple one-or-two line statement.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `ActiveSheet.Calculate` to `Application.Calculate` to take account of uncalculated dependencies as @Charles Williams suggested.

For detecting column filtering action while the workbook is set to manual calculation, i changed the very first cell in each filtered column to a `ComboBox` with dynamic `.ListFillRange` in order to be able to trigger `Application.Calculate` action upon change.